# mySQL query joining five tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following five tables (some fields omitted for brevity)

```
(campaign)
campaign_id
===========
campaign_name
campaign_description


(ad_group)
campaign_id
===========
group_id
===========
group_name


(used_ad)
campaign_id
===========
group_id
===========
ad_id
===========


(billboard_group)
campaign_id
===========
group_id
===========
group_name


(used_billboard)
campaign_id
==============
group_id
==============
billboard_code
==============
```

So a "campaign" is made up of 1) an "ad_group", and 2) a "billboard_group". The ad_group contains many ads (stored in the "used_ad" group), and the billboard_group contains many billboards (stored in the "used_billboard" group).

I want to run a query that will return all of the campaigns, and list the total number of ads and billboards that are related to that campaign. I've been able to do this for ad_group only, but not ad_group AND billboard_group.

For example, this query:

```
SELECT campaign.*, COUNT(used_ad.ad_id) AS used_ads
FROM campaign
LEFT JOIN ad_group 
  ON campaign.campaign_id = ad_group.campaign_id
LEFT JOIN used_ad
  ON ad_group.group_id = used_ad.group_id
  AND used_ad.campaign_id = campaign.campaign_id
GROUP BY campaign.campaign_id
```

Gives a listing like this:

```
campaign_id     campaign_name     campaign_description    used_ads
1               Test campaign     Testing                 4
2               Second campaign   Second                  0
```

But what I'm after is:

```
campaign_id     campaign_name     campaign_description    used_ads    used_billboards
1               Test campaign     Testing                 4           5
2               Second campaign   Second                  0           3
```

Only I can't seem to figure out how to include counts from BOTH used_ad and used_billboard. I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: try this by just adding billboard condition as you did for ads

SELECT campaign.*, COUNT(used_ad.ad_id) AS used_ads, COUNT(used_billboard.billboard_code) as used_billboards
FROM campaign
LEFT JOIN ad_group 
  ON campaign.campaign_id = ad_group.campaign_id
LEFT JOIN used_ad
  ON ad_group.group_id = used_ad.group_id
  AND used_ad.campaign_id = campaign.campaign_id
LEFT JOIN used_billboard
  ON ad_group.group_id = billboard_group.group_id
  AND used_billboard.campaign_id = campaign.campaign_id
GROUP BY campaign.campaign_id

Comment: are you able to solve your issue by answers given by others?

Comment: check the query i put up as answer

Comment: @Rajen-Raiyarela Thank you very much for the reply, I appreciate your help. mySQL gives me an error: #1054 - Unknown column 'billboard_group.group_id' in 'on clause'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid Cartesian multiplications, I'd group and count `used_ad` and `used_billboard` separately and only then join them:

```
SELECT campaign.*, ag.used_ads_count, bg.used_billboards_count
FROM campaign c
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT    campaign_id, COUNT(*) AS used_ads_count
            FROM      ad_group ag
            LEFT JOIN used_ad ua ON ag.group_id = ua.group_id
            GROUP BY  campaign_id) ac ON c.campaign_id = ac.campaign_id
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT    campaign_id, COUNT(*) AS used_billboards_count
            FROM      billboard_group bg
            LEFT JOIN used_billboard ub ON bg.group_id = ub.group_id
            GROUP BY  campaign_id) bc ON c.campaign_id = bc.campaign_id
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer. That sounds very promising, but at the moment mySQL is telling me "#1052 - Column 'campaign_id' in field list is ambiguous". I tried changing this to 'c.campaign_id' and 'campaign.campaign_id', but in that instance it says, e.g., "#1054 - Unknown column 'c.campaign_id' in 'field list' "

Comment: Ah-huh! With a couple of minor modification it does works (sorry for lost formatting): SELECT c.*, ac.used_ads_count, bc.used_billboards_count
FROM campaign c LEFT JOIN  (SELECT ag.campaign_id, COUNT(*) AS used_ads_count FROM ad_group ag LEFT JOIN used_ad ua ON ag.group_id = ua.group_id GROUP BY ag.campaign_id) ac ON c.campaign_id = ac.campaign_id LEFT JOIN  (SELECT bg.campaign_id, COUNT(*) AS used_billboards_count FROM billboard_group bg LEFT JOIN used_billboard ub ON bg.group_id = ub.group_id GROUP BY bg.campaign_id) bc ON c.campaign_id = bc.campaign_id - thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work if billboard_code is unique:

```
SELECT
  c.campaign_id, c.campaign_name, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT u.ad_id) AS used_ads,
  COUNT(DISTINCT b.billboard_code) AS used_billboards
FROM
campaign c
LEFT JOIN ad_group a ON c.campaign_id = a.campaign_id
LEFT JOIN used_ad u ON a.group_id = u.group_id
  AND c.campaign_id = u.campaign_id
LEFT JOIN used_billboard b ON c.campaign_id = b.campaign_id
  AND b.group_id = a.group_id
GROUP BY c.campaign_id
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying: yes, billboard_code is unique. That very nearly works, but in some cases it gives a "used_billboards" count of zero when there are values in the "used_billboard" table for a campaign. I'm going a bit cross-eyed at the moment trying to figure out why this is so!

Comment: My first thought is, I probably should have used this instead for the GROUP BY : `GROUP BY c.campaign_id, c.campaign_name`.  I think your GROUP BY is typically supposed to have all non-aggregated columns in it.  Let me think about it to see if I can figure out what else might be wrong.

Comment: Also, can you confirm for each row in used_billboard, there is a corresponding row in used_ad?  If not, you can simply remove the last `AND b.group_id = a.group_id` clause.  In fact, I'd try that and my guess is that it will work fine for you.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Yes! Indeed, with the edits you suggested it returns the expected results, thank you very much indeed. I've already awarded the "accepted answer" to Mureinik, I'm not sure I can do that for more than one answer, but I'll give it a try. Thank you so much for your patience and persistence! I suppose now I'll have to ruminate on which is the most efficient way of running the query. Best regards

Comment: Oh, seems I can only set one "accepted answer" - which makes sense really. I wish I could reward you in some other way, but you certainly have my gratitude

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT campaign.*, COUNT(used_ad.ad_id) AS used_ads, COUNT(used_billboard.billboard_code) as used_billboards
FROM campaign
LEFT JOIN ad_group 
  ON campaign.campaign_id = ad_group.campaign_id
LEFT JOIN billboard_group
  ON campaign.campaign_id = billboard_group.campaign_id
LEFT JOIN used_ad
  ON ad_group.group_id = used_ad.group_id
  AND used_ad.campaign_id = campaign.campaign_id
LEFT JOIN used_billboard
  ON billboard_group.group_id = used_billboard.group_id
  AND used_billboard.campaign_id = campaign.campaign_id
GROUP BY campaign.campaign_id
```

Comment: Rajen - I really appreciate all of the time you've put in to this. That's almost there, but it gives me double the intended count - what I mean is, if there are 3 ads in a campaign, used_ads_count will show 6. But thank you so much for your efforts